# Modern Win7 Open/Save dialog for Delphi 7 app

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Im using Delphi7 with TNT controls. Is there a way to call modern Open/Save dialogs on Win7? Maybe a patch to VCL, patch to TNT? TNT patch is preferred as I need Unicode aware dialogs, but VCL patch may be needed (less) too.

Comment: Certainly. (Essentially) every part of the Windows API can be used from Delphi (even old versions). Start [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx), as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to call the API functions [`GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx) and [`GetSaveFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646928.aspx) directly. These will, unless you use some of the more esoteric functionality, show the modern dialogs on Vista and up.

Obviously you'll need to call the W variants, and pass the W versions of the structs.

Here's the simplest example I can construct:

```
var
  ofn: TOpenFilenameW;
  FileName: array [0..MAX_PATH-1] of WideChar;
begin
  FillChar(ofn, SizeOf(ofn), 0);
  ofn.lStructSize := SizeOf(ofn);
  ofn.hWndOwner := Handle;
  ofn.lpstrFilter := 'All files'#0'*.*'#0;
  FileName[0] := #0;
  ofn.lpstrFile := @FileName;
  ofn.nMaxFile := Length(FileName);
  ofn.lpstrTitle := 'Select File';
  if GetOpenFileNameW(ofn) then
    MessageBoxW(Handle, FileName, nil, MB_OK);
end;
```

Naturally you can expand this to have more functionality.

Comment: Rather than rely on `GetOpenFileNameW()` and `GetSaveFileNameW()` calling the modern dialogs, which is not guaranteed, you should instead access the `IFileOpenDialog` and `IFileSaveDialog` COM interfaces directly to ensure you do get the modern dialogs as expected. I use those interfaces in BCB/Delphi 6, they work fine, they just have to be declared manually, that's all.

Comment: You can do that, but then you end up writing two versions of the code, one for XP and one for later.

Comment: It is very easy to handle that, though. Try `CoCreateInstance()` first (or at least an OS version check) and if it succeeds then use the interfaces, otherwise fallback to the other functions. It is not like they are overly complicated dialogs, not a lot of code involved.

Comment: @Remy Yes it's easy enough to handle. But it still has to be done. My code does exactly what you describe.